# Cell Fracture, UV Texture Distorted

Tags: uv

If I fracture a box/cylinder/sphere with texture applied, everything goes smoothly, but if I edit the box/cylinder/sphere (e.g. added Loopcuts) and then edited the UV coordinators of the loopcuts, things go distorted.

[image: Distorted Picture]

I'm thinking if there is a way to apply the UV, so its a single picture that the object don't need loopcuts to map the image on?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: that's what cell fracture does

Comment: Yeah, but it'll be nice if there is a way I can keep the UV texture

Comment: You could try using a *UV project* modifier

Comment: you can try a box projection (texture node) with generated or object texture coordinates

Comment: `I'm thinking if there is a way to apply the UV, so its a single picture that the object don't need loopcuts to map the image on?` You should not need loop cuts unless the texture is uneven, you can just move the end vertices on the UV map.

Comment: Because I'm using the same square texture for all 4 sides of a rectangular prism (not ideal I know...), and if I use loop cuts, I can still have the edges be the same width, and just stretch the middle wood plank textures.